# Statistics problem about a distribution of populations and an asteroid

Tags: statistics

*I made this problem up after reading about mass extinctions. My statistics are a little rusty, but I still think this problem is kind of fun.*

An asteroid wipes out 75% of all species of animal on earth.
There are 1000 species. The populations of the species are normally distributed around 1 million with standard deviation of 100,000. A species is considered extinct if reduced to 0 individuals.

1. Before the asteroid hits what is the total population of individual
   creatures on earth?
2. What is the maximum and minimum percent reduction in the total
   population of individual creatures on earth?
3. If every species is equally likely to end up extinct (that is, going
   extinct is not dependent on population size*) what is the expected
   percent reduction in the total population of individual creatures on
   earth?

This seems almost too simple for the first question. I thought about the implied normal curve, which would be discrete up close. The standard deviation isn't really important for the first question.
total pop = 1000 species * 1000000 mean population = 1 Billion creatures

For the second question I want proportions of that same 1 Billion. To eliminate the maximum possible creatures we take those with the largest populations first. P(X<x)=.25, looking it up I have $x \approx 932,551$ so I need to add up all of the populations less than $\approx 932,551$. (It seems like I might need to make a representative discrete distribution to make this make any sense, but I kept going anyways) I thought something like:

$$\int_{932551}^{\infty} \frac{1000x}{100000 \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-1000000}{100000}\right)^2}dx \approx 781,778,000$$

Might work. For the minimum:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{1067449} \frac{1000x}{100000 \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-1000000}{100000}\right)^2}dx \approx 718,222,000$$

It's the normal distribution function multiplied by 1000x for the individual populations. These are upper and lower bounds around 75% of 1 billion as expected, but I didn't expect it to be this tight. That is, I thought that the maximum hit to the total population of individual creatures would be a lot more than just 78%. Not feeling totally confident about this one. I also wonder if there is a more elegant way.

I'm fairly certain the answer to the third question I made up is just 75%... provided that my integrals made sense.

*In a more realistic model species with smaller populations would be at greater risk of extinction.

---

Update: I don't think my "maximum" value works since only 750 animals need to survive. So the maximum would be 999,999,250. The minimum should still work.

This would then change the expected value ... Maybe I should just model this.

Comment: You say the asteroid kills 75% of *species*, not animals. Are we to assume then that surviving species have their populations intact?

Comment: If there is one member of a species left it's not extinct. So they may or may not have taken losses. 
All members must be gone for it to count as an extinction.

Comment: Great. I see a problem with my maximum value now. It could be a whole lot higher. Only 750 animals need to survive. But I think the minimum still makes sense.

Comment: Unless a species is parthenogenic, I think you could consider it effectively extinct if only one member left alive ...